# How to delete a REG_MULTI_SZ via location and data with CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I have a batch that goes through and deletes registry entries. So far all but one one of them has been sussed out successfully using CMD.

Let's say we have the following key:

```
HKCU\Temp
```

This key has a REG_MULTI_SZ value with an unknown name.  We know which key the value is in, and we know the data stored in the value, but not the name of the value.  Deleting the entire key (or all values in the key) isn't permissible: we want to delete only the value containing the data that we're looking for.

As an example, suppose we know that the key is HKCU\Temp and the value contains three strings:

```
This is a test
for
now at least
```

I've tried a couple different ways to delete this registry entry using CMD, but I'm goofing somewhere. What command would I enter to delete this guy?

**Caveat:** We cannot assume there aren't other entries at this key that have the same content on the first line. It has to be a full match.

**Important comment promoted:** "**reg delete** can only delete keys and values with explicitly specified names, it can't search for data." -wOxxOm

Therefore, you must search the data for a match, and then delete the matching key/value.

Comment: "As currently written, your question asks how to delete TestValue if you mustn't delete TestValue." Apologies for the misunderstanding. I asked how to delete TestValue by not knowing TestValue's label, but rather scanning the multiline contents of the data. I know the key that holds TestValue, but TestValue itself is dynamically named with no known schema to follow. I only have the data contents to help figure out which one I'm deleting, thus the predicament of the title question.

Comment: OK, I've rewritten the question to make that clearer.  Just as an aside, you'd probably be better off using vbscript for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a multiline string use `\0` separator and `/e` for exact matching, the output will be:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Temp
    abc    REG_MULTI_SZ    This is a test\0for\0now at least

End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Let's filter it by `"REG_MULTI_SZ"`, parse the result and delete the value.

1. Simple method: take the 1st space-separated token, works only for value names without spaces

   ```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('
       reg query "HKCU\Temp" /d /e /f "This is a test\0for\0now at least"
       ^| find "REG_MULTI_SZ"
   ') do (
       echo Deleting %%a=%%c
       reg delete "HKCU\Temp" /v %%a /f
   )
   pause
   ```
2. More robust method that can also delete variable names with spaces:

   ```
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
       reg query "HKCU\Temp" /d /e /f "This is a test\0for\0now at least"
       ^| find "REG_MULTI_SZ"
   ') do (
       setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

       rem Split
       set "line=%%a"
       set "value=!line:*REG_MULTI_SZ=REG_MULTI_SZ!"
       call set "name=%%line:!value!=%%"

       rem Trim spaces
       for /L %%b in (1,1,10) do if "!name:~-1!"==" " set "name=!name:~0,-1!"

       echo Deleting !name!
       reg delete "HKCU\Temp" /v "!name!" /f

       endlocal
   )
   pause
   ```

Comment: So close! My fault for not being more specific in the question. I've updated it to reflect the fact that all three lines of the REG_MULTI_SZ have to match, as there might be other values that have the same data shared on one or more line. They're always 3 lines with whitespace in at least one line. Maybe that's an easy edit with the provided answer, but I have a stupendously difficult time reading CMD syntax. If you could update it for that, I will mark this as the answer! :)

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, yes, this is easy. See the updated code.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, very much! So if I understood correctly, instead of directly deleting the registry value based on data content, you're scanning the data content and sending the value label match to deletion.

Comment: `reg delete` can only delete keys and values with explicitly specified names, it can't search for data.